# Best way to change dictionary key

Tags: c#, dictionary

I am wondering is there a better way to change a dictionary key, for example:

```
var dic = new Dictionary<string, int>();
dic.Add("a", 1);
```

and later on I decided to make key value pair to be ("b" , 1) , is it possible to just rename the key rather than add a new key value pair of ("b",1) and then remove "a" ?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

No, you cannot rename keys once that have been added to a Dictionary. If you want a rename facility, perhaps add your own extension method:

```
public static void RenameKey<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dic,
                                      TKey fromKey, TKey toKey)
{
  TValue value = dic[fromKey];
  dic.Remove(fromKey);
  dic[toKey] = value;
}
```

Comment: A better naming is `ChangeKey` or `UpdateKey` :)

Comment: `dic[toKey] = value` will replace the value of `toKey` if it existed. You should check if the target key exists before allowing the rename.

Answer (score 35):

The `Dictionary` in c# is implemented as a hashtable. Therefore, if you were able to change the key via some `Dictionary.ChangeKey` method, the entry would have to be re-hashed. So it's not really any different (aside from convenience) than removing the entry, and then adding it again with the new key.

Answer (score 13):

```
public static bool ChangeKey<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dict, 
                                           TKey oldKey, TKey newKey)
{
    TValue value;
    if (!dict.TryGetValue(oldKey, out value))
        return false;

    dict.Remove(oldKey);
    dict[newKey] = value;  // or dict.Add(newKey, value) depending on ur comfort
    return true;
}
```

Same as Colin's answer, but doesn't throw exception, instead returns `false` on failure. In fact I'm of the opinion that such a method should be default in dictionary class considering that editing the key value is dangerous, so the class itself should give us an option to be safe.

---

Starting with .NET Core, this is more efficient:

```
public static bool ChangeKey<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dict, 
                                           TKey oldKey, TKey newKey)
{
    TValue value;
    if (!dict.Remove(oldKey, out value))
        return false;

    dict[newKey] = value;  // or dict.Add(newKey, value) depending on ur comfort
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I like this approach, it's safe, allows for a gacefull fail if need be, but I'm going to change it ever so slightly as the edge case I'm looking at solving needs to take the key names as strings.

Comment: And now you remove `TValue value;` and use `dict.Remove(oldKey, out var value)` :)

Answer (score 7):

**Do you like this simple code?**

```
var newDictionary= oldDictionary.ReplaceInKeys<object>("_","-");
```

> It replace `'_'` with `'-'` in all keys

---

**If**

- type of your `key` is `string`

**and**

- you want **replace** a string with other string **in all keys** of the dictionary

**then** use my way

---

You just need to add the following class to your app:

```
public static class DicExtensions{

    public static void ReplaceInKeys<TValue>(this IDictionary<string, TValue> oldDictionary, string replaceIt, string withIt)
    {
          // Do all the works with just one line of code:
          return oldDictionary
                 .Select(x=> new KeyValuePair<string, TValue>(x.Key.Replace(replaceIt, withIt), x.Value))
                 .ToDictionary(x=> x.Key,x=> x.Value);
    }
}
```

> I use **Linq** to change my dictionary keys *(regenerate a dictionary by `linq`)*
>
> The magic step is **`ToDictionary()`** method.

---

> **Note:** We can make an advanced ***Select*** include a block of codes for complicated cases instead of a simple lambda.

```
Select(item =>{
            .....Write your Logic Codes Here....

            return resultKeyValuePair;
       })
```

Comment: Seems a bit fast and loose with memory allocation this method, not gonna down vote it, but am gonna avoid it purely on the memory allocation smell, just a little bit on the dangerous side of things for my liking.

Comment: The middle `Select` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Easy way to achieve the outcome of changing the keys (if you need to do it in bulk) is by projecting a new dictionary using System.Linq:

`var rehashedDictionary = existingDictionary.ToDictionary(kvp => $"newkey-{kvp.Key}", kvp => kvp.Value);`

If you are dealing with large collections you may want to use something more specialized for performance.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary `KeyValuePair`'s in C# maintain their order until a entry is removed. All keys following a removed key's position are then shifted up one position.

You can, however, use [Linq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/) and an [Extension Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) to make an **expensive**, yet versatile function that renames your key, and maintains the order and value references.

I want to reiterate that this is **very expensive** and **should not** be used inside a loop. Use this when **infrequent renaming** is required.

```
using System.Linq;

public static class DictionaryExtensions
{
    ///<Summary> A relatively expensive operation to rename keys</Summary>
    public static void RenameKey<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dict, TKey from, TKey to)
    {                  
        Dictionary<TKey, TValue>  temp = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>(dict);
        dict.Clear();
        for(int i = 0; i < temp.Count; i++)
        {
            var kvp = temp.ElementAt(i);

            if(kvp.Key.Equals(from))
                dict.Add(to, temp[from]);
            else 
                dict.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
dict.RenameKey(oldName, newName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to nawfal's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15728577/11178549), with the difference that the key is changed only if both conditions are true:

1. The old key exists.
2. The new key does not exist.

```
/// <summary>Attempts to change the key of a value in the dictionary.</summary>
public static bool TryChangeKey<TKey, TValue>(
    this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> source, TKey oldKey, TKey newKey, out TValue value)
{
    if (source.ContainsKey(newKey)) { value = default; return false; }
    if (!source.Remove(oldKey, out value)) return false;
    source.Add(newKey, value);
    return true;
}
```

Usage:

```
if (myDictionary.TryChangeKey(oldKey, newKey, out var value))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Key of {value} changed from {oldKey} to {newKey}.");
}
```