# Changing the Key of a Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I am very new to dictionaries. Very new meaning that I started using them about 6 hours ago :p. Anyways, I want to know if there is a way to change the key of a dictionary.

Here is my dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, string> Information = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

Here is how I am adding to the dictionary (this is fired every time the user enters info and hits a button:

```
Information.Add(txtObjectNumber.Text, addressCombined);
```

The user needs to be able to edit both fields as well as remove the whole record.

So pretty much the application needs to add `txtNumber` and `txtComments` where `txtNumber = txtObjectNumber`

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Where do `txtNumber` and `txtComments` appear in your code? Are you sure you want to use a dictionary rather than a list of objects that store two (or more) values?

Comment: You are probably not using the right data structure.

Comment: sorry those are just the textboxes the the user can enter data into.I definitely should have been more clear.

Comment: @Oded : Yeah I am starting to think about just doing an array, but the Dictionary was working very well until now :/

Comment: If you are using .NET 4.0, look a the [`Tuple`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) classes.

Comment: Wow, that is pretty cool. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to change dictionary key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499334/best-way-to-change-dictionary-key)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is the mechanism that will allow you to find the data (the "value") later.

For example, if you did

```
information.Add("Kris", "Vandermotten");
```

you'd be able to find "Vandermotten" back later if you know "Kris".

Now in that context, what does it mean to *change* "Kris"? You put data in under the name "Kris" and want to get it back out searching for "Bob"? You won't find it.

In a way, dictionary key's are very much like primary keys in a relational database. The refer to the logical identity of the value. So for one thing, they should be uniquely identifying it.

So maybe this example doesn't make sense. Maybe something like

```
information.Add(42, new Person("Kris", "Vandermotten")
```

makes more sense. The question then of course is: what's the 42? Sometimes there is a natural candidate for such a key, like an employee number or something,  sometimes there isn't.

When there is none, maybe you need to do

```
List<Person> information = new List<Person>();

information.Add(new Person("Kris", "Vandermotten"));
```

And of course, if a Person object allows changing the first name property, and that's what you want to do, then do it. But "changing dictionary keys" doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

Comment: I was reading your example and was like, where did he get "Vandermotten" from. Then I saw your name at the end. My only thought was, awesome name.

Comment: @CalvinSmith Thanks. My dad gave it to me. I'll pass your comment along. ;-)

Answer (score 11):

It is not possible to directly modify a key. You'd have to remove it and re-add it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the built-in Remove() method for your Dictionary. Or you could do it the hard way by iterating through the collection. Although I'm curious as to why you would need to have to constantly update the keys, and not the values only.

Comment: I need to do both. Pretty much the keys are water meter product numbers. When one is replaced the product key will change and the comments may or may not change. The address will need to stay the same though.

Comment: That sounds like maybe you need a Dictionary<Address, ProductNumber> and a Dictionary<Address, CommentList>

Comment: Dang... Why did I not think about that haha. Thanks, you just saved me from having to change a lot of things. It might get a bit messy, but it should work haha.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the key of an existing dictionnary item. What you could do is delete the previous key and add a new key/value based on the edit.

Example use case:

Add Key:Name, Value: Bob

Now you want to change `Name` to `FirstName`, you would have to do

Remove key `Name` from dictionnary
Add Key:FirstName, Value: Bob

Answer (score 0):

Your use of a dictionary here seems a bit off. Like the name suggests, dictionaries are intended to provide you a way to "look up" a value, based on the key. In your case, though, you seem to be using it to store two related pieces of data, either of which can change. In that case, you're probably better off just using a list, and creating a separate class that encapsulates both pieces of information. Something like

```
public class MyData
{
    public string SomeData { get; set; }
    public string OtherData { get; set; }
}
```

and then

```
List<MyData> myDataList;
```

Or, you might even want to have a dictionary that maps a non-changing key (maybe a user id) to the custom class:

```
Dictionary<string, MyData> myDataDictionary;
```