# how to dynamically change the key in dictionary in c#?

Tags: c#

I have the following code in c# , basically its a simple dictionary
with some keys and their values . Now i want to update the existing key in
this dictionary with new key. Is it possible?

```
Dictionary<string, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
dictionary.Add("00", 2);
dictionary.Add("01", 1);
dictionary.Add("02", 0);
dictionary.Add("03", -1);
```

In certain conditions I removed the value with key 01.

Now I have to update the key below the deleted key like below.

```
dictionary.Add("00", 2);   
dictionary.Add("01", 0);
dictionary.Add("02", -1);
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That suggests you are using a dictionary entirely incorrectly. A dictionary is a mapping between keys and values. If we erase a word from "the" dictionary (the thing with words), the definitions don't all move by one word!

To do what you want, just use a list, and use the *index* in place of how you are currently using the *key*:

```
var list = new List<int>();
list.Add(2);
list.Add(1);
list.Add(0);
list.Add(-1);
//...
list.RemoveAt(1);
```

now the list is {index, value}: `{0, 2}, {1, 0}, {2, -1}`

Comment: He can then convert them into Dictionary with index as key and value as value.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal yes, but why would you do that when you can just use the list indexer, i.e. `list[2] = 8; Console.WriteLine(list[0]);` ?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using a dictionary in the first place? It looks like you should be using a list or array.

Comment: Actually what is my requirement is

Comment: I have to add properties window for each chart series in chart. The series may be in any chart area like chartarea1,chartarea2... There may be any no.of series. I added based on the index chartareano+seriesno. Here whats my actual problem is while deleting the series the corresponding properties should be deleted. and also other properties window index should be reduced by seriesno-1.

Comment: I have to admit that I don't fully understand what you need. And I am still not convinced that a dictionary is the best structure to use. From the sounds of it, you should assign proper IDs to all your objects and never reference them by their index in a data structure. Deleting one element from a dictionary should not effect the others.

Answer (score 0):

You want an 'AddOrUpdate' method:

```
static class DictionaryExtensions
{
    public static void AddOrUpdate<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dict, TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        if (dict.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            dict[key] = value;
        }
        else
        {
            dict.Add(key, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
Dictionary<string, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
dictionary.AddOrUpdate("00", 2);
```

Comment: the question seems to relate more to an unusual intend when *removing*; look at how the keys/values shift after removing `01` (in the question)

Comment: This is not related to the question. And to just `AddOrUpdate` as your method suggests, `dict[key] = value;` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it however you will get the same effect if you remove the key and then add it again. The Dictionary is implemented using hashtable, so if you somehow changed the key, the entry must of been rehashed.

Here is an extension of how you might go about doing it (similar to referenced SO question):

```
public static UpdateKeyName<TKey, TValue>(Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dic this,
                                      TKey fromKey, TKey toKey)
{
  TValue value = dic[fromKey];
  dic.Remove(froKeym);
  dic[toKey] = value;
}
```

further info on dictionaries in c# can be found here:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx
- [Best way to change dictionary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499334/best-way-to-change-dictionary-key)

Comment: this is not related to the question.