# Naming an Object with variable content to serialize in json file

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm trying to serialize an object to a JSON file, but the problem is that I want to give the JSON object a variable content name.

I thought I could do something like this :

```
string codfis = "Example1";

var jsonCF = new {
    codfis = new { // codfis is the name of the variable as you can see
        Cognome = vcgm,
        Nome = vnm,
        Sesso = ss,
        LuogoDiNascita = ldn,
        Provincia = pr,
        DataDiNascita = ddn
    }
};
using (StreamWriter file = File.CreateText("CodFisCalcolati.json")) {
    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    serializer.Serialize(file, jsonCF);
}
```

But obviosly this didn't do what I want :

```
{
    "codfis": { // it named the json object like this, and not "Example1" like above
        "Cognome": "Yoyo",
        "Nome": "OK!",
        "Sesso": "Nice",
        "LuogoDiNascita": "Good",
        "Provincia": "Perfect",
        "DataDiNascita": "Fine"
    }
}
```

I also tried with this :

```
string codfis = "Example1";

var jsonCF = new {
    [codfis] = new { // putting brackets on the variable
        Cognome = vcgm,
        Nome = vnm,
        Sesso = ss,
        LuogoDiNascita = ldn,
        Provincia = pr,
        DataDiNascita = ddn
    }
};
```

but it gives me a syntax error.

So i just want to make this...

```
{
    "Example1": {
        "Cognome": "Yoyo",
        "Nome": "OK!",
        "Sesso": "Nice",
        "LuogoDiNascita": "Good",
        "Provincia": "Perfect",
        "DataDiNascita": "Fine"
    }
}
```

how can I do it ?

Comment: use a dictionary, not an anonymous object.

Comment: You initialize an object called `codfis` inside an initialized object called `jsonCF`. It's no strange behavior that it does not treat it like a variable and tries to get its value.
EDIT: maybe after creating the object you should try to access `codfis` `key` and change its name to the value of `codfis` variable.

Comment: @DanielA.White can you please explain how? I always used dictionaries just to, for example, get an integer for a char...

Comment: @FotisPapadamis wait, i half understood it, can you explain it with some code ?

Comment: @zAlweNy26 create a dictionary with the key-value pairs you do want to have. Now to overcome the false `codfis` key take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499334/best-way-to-change-dictionary-key)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As other OPS mentioned in the comments, create dictionary and serialize it

```
string codfis = "Example1";
var codfisValue = new
{ // codfis is the name of the variable as you can see
    Cognome = "vcgm",
    Nome = "vnm",
    Sesso = "ss",
    LuogoDiNascita = "ldn",
    Provincia = "pr",
    DataDiNascita = "ddn"
};
var jsonCF = new Dictionary<string, object>();
jsonCF.Add(codfis, codfisValue);


using (StreamWriter file = File.CreateText("CodFisCalcolati.json"))
{
    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    serializer.Serialize(file, jsonCF);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The fact that this is anonymous object aside, this is actually being serialized correctly.  The codfis object initialized outside of the jsonCF object is never used. you actually are creating a completely new object to represent the property inside of your object.

The "solution" depends on what it is that you want to do with this serialized item. You just need to reference your existing variable instead of creating a new one if that's what you are after.  Alternatively, if you just want the name of that property to be `Example1`, just set it to that like so:

```
    var jsonCF = new {
    Example1 = new { //Note the property name
        Cognome = vcgm,
        Nome = vnm,
        Sesso = ss,
        LuogoDiNascita = ldn,
        Provincia = pr,
        DataDiNascita = ddn
    }
};
```

Alternatively,

```
var codfis = new {
        Cognome = vcgm,
        Nome = vnm,
        Sesso = ss,
        LuogoDiNascita = ldn,
        Provincia = pr,
        DataDiNascita = ddn
    };

var jsonConf = new {

     Example1 = codfis
}
```

If you want both the property name and value to vary, you might be after a dictionary instead that way you could do

```
var codfisName = "Example1";
var jsonConf = new Dictionary<string, object>{

     {codfisName, codfis}
};
```

Comment: as i wrote in the question, i want to create a json object with the content of the variable "codfis", so what do you mean with reference it ?

Comment: Your "codfis" object is just a string that says "example 1"  if you want to use that variable, turn it into an object like your "Example1".  Then, reference it inside of jsonCF.  However, if you want the name of the property to be "Example1" you have to change to that.

Comment: but i put it in a variable because it can vary, it can become "Example2", "Example3", ecc...

Comment: The name of the property your variable sits in will not change though.  The name of the variable is always going to be the same.  So right now you have a completely new object inside of your "codfis" property.  That makes sense.  However your variable outside of that object is literally just a string that says "Example1"  and is not being used anywhere.

Comment: i mean, the content of the variable will vary

Comment: Correct.  So, assign that changing variable to your property.

Comment: but it doesn't work, in the json file the json object as the name of the variable (so it's "codfis") and not the CONTENT of the variable (like "Example1"). sorry man maybe i didn't understand what are you saying...

Comment: Oh, got it.  Ok, use a dictionary then.  I updated my above answer, but the other answer gives more detail and safer operations.