# Replace dictionary keys in brackets with values via regex

Tags: c#, regex, dictionary

I have a dictionary, for example:

```
var d = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    d.Add("key1", "value1");
    d.Add("key2", "value2");
    d.Add("key3", "value3");
```

I have input string, for example:

```
    var str = "[key1] - [key3]";
```

The result string should be:

```
"value1 - value3"
```

How can I achieve this with help of Regex?

Comment: Why would you even consider a regex here? A loop and `String.Replace` would seem to be good enough (with a `StringBuilder` to minimize allocation).

Comment: @JeroenMostert that should work. I'll try this out.

Comment: @JeroenMostert that's not a bad code golf exercise, although relatively pointless here.

Comment: [You can't change a Key. You must create a new entry and remove the old one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499334/best-way-to-change-dictionary-key)

Comment: http://ideone.com/LwqOr1

Comment: I just spent 5 minutes writing the answer!!!!! `var regex=new Regex("\\[(?<key>.*?)\\]");

regex.Replace(str,m=>d[m.Groups["key"].Value])`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for closing right before I posted the answer

Comment: That is a wrong solution anyway. See mine above.