# Binding dictionary key to input text field in Blazor

Tags: c#, dictionary, asp.net-core, binding, blazor

I want to bind the value of an input text box in Blazor to the key of a dictionary. Now I know I would have to logically remove the current key and set the new name for the key with the value but I am unsure of how to go about it.

```
<input type="text" name="identifier" @bind="@Keyword!.Key" required/>
```

Dictionary:
Keywords : {
"Name1" : {
some values
},
"Name2" : {
some more values
}
}

Comment: I advise you use a List<NewClass> instead, NewClass being a class created for the situation. It will probably be easier and more adapted to your issue. Otherwise, I don't believe you will be able to bind to the Key directly. You would have to create a logic to make the changes reflect in the dictionary.

Comment: @Ayushi, instead of asking how to do what you should for sure not do, why don't you explain what you're trying to achieve, and we can show you how to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Could you pls try this code?

```
<button onclick="@changeValue">click</button>
<input @onchange=@(async(e) => updateInput1(e)) value="@Keywords["Key1"]" />

@code{
    public Dictionary<string, string> Keywords { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Keywords ??= new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "Key1", "value4Key1"}
        };
    }
    
    public void updateInput1(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        var newValue = e.Value;
        Keywords["Key1"] = newValue.ToString();
    }
    
    public void changeValue()
    {
        Keywords["Key1"] = "new value for Key1";
    }
}
```

If we want to "bind the key of a dictionary", maybe we could try code like this, because we don't have a "changeKey" method, like this high [voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6499344) said.

```
public void changeValue()
{
    // Keywords["Key1"] = "new value for Key1";
    newKey = "new value in the input";
    var value = Keywords[oldKey];
    Keywords[newKey] = value;
    Keywords.Remove(oldKey);
    oldKey = newKey;
}

public void updateInput1(ChangeEventArgs e)
{
    newKey = e.Value.ToString();//make sure it's not null
    var value = Keywords[oldKey];
    Keywords[newKey] = value;
    Keywords.Remove(oldKey);
    oldKey = newKey;
    // Keywords["Key1"] = newValue.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I don't think you understood the question: he wants to bind the key of a dictionary, not the value corresponding to that key.

Comment: then it looks like a "special" requirement...